# d3.js - Change link colour to child node depending on child d.data.type

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to change the colour of the link from parent to child nodes depending on the d.data.type of the child node.

Note this should only be for the link between parent and child, not going back to ancestors.

So in the example below, the link from A to A4 would be the colour of the stroke of node A4 (purple).

It would be even better if this graduated from parent colour to child colour, but not absolutely  necessary.

[image]

The colour of the stroke of nodes is set on d.data.type, e.g.:

```
   .style("stroke", function(d) {
            if (d.class !== "found") {
                if(d.data.type == "unit1") return "brown";
                if(d.data.type == "unit2") return "purple";
             }
                if (d.class === "found") {
                    return "#ff4136"; //red
                } else {
                    return colourScale(findParent(d));
                }
            });
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nquef9cz/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same function for `links`:

```js
  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr('d', function(d) {
                return diagonal(d, d.parent)
            })
            .style( "stroke", function ( d ) {
                        if(d.data.type == "unit1") return "brown";
                        if(d.data.type == "unit2") return "purple";
                        if ( d.class === "found" ) {
                            return "#ff4136";
                        } else {
                            return colourScale( findParentLinks( d ) );
                        }
                    } );
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljwuyos7/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Using d3.js version 3.4.11, I had to use:

```
  link.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr('d', function(d) {
                return diagonal(d, d.parent)
            })
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
                    if(d.target.type == "learning_event") return "#809eff";
                    if(d.target.type == "assessment") return "#74c26a";
                if (d.target.class === "found") {
                    return "#ff4136";
                } else {
                    return colourScale(findParentLinks(d));
                }
            });
```